# Drupal hook_menu() not working

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've tried the simplest examples of using hook_menu() posted here and on other Drupal forms and noting seems to work. My code, in: /sites/themes/mytheme/mymodule.module, is as follows:

```
<?php
function helloworld_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['hello'] = array(
        'title' => 'Hello world!',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'helloworld_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}

function helloworld_page() {
    return 'Hello world !';
}
```

When I navigate to www.mydomain.com/hello I get a 404 error. I've tried enabling and disabling the module along with clearing the cache numerous times with no luck still. Here is some additional information about my environment:

- Running Drupal Commerce version 7.22
- I've enabled clean URLS and pathauto module

The end goal I'm trying to achieve is adding products to the cart with a link. I already have that part working so that I can pass product ID's into a function and add them to cart. I would be replacing helloworld_page() with my function and then changing $items['hello'] to $items['cart/add/%/%'], having two wildcards (product ID and quantity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a hook declaration like `hook_menu`, the function name should be like `<your_module_name_here>_menu`

This is where you are going wrong.

Your module name is `mymodule.module` so your hook_menu should be called, `mymodule_menu`

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['hello'] = array(
        'title' => 'Hello world!',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'helloworld_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}

function helloworld_page() {
    return 'Hello world !';
}
```

Please correct the function name and clear your cache and try again.

ALso i noticed you put the module in an unconventional location.

Please move it to `/sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule` folder ( both `mymodule.info` and `mymodule.module` files ).

Comment: Wow, I didn't think function name (other than "_menu") mattered or the location of the module. Also, I was using only dummy data but it still worked, thanks a ton!